# How to make batch insert in Oracle Database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I need to a make batch insert into an Oracle DB, but I am confused with how to make that batch.

```
String INSERT = "INSERT INTO LOGS(METHOD,USER,START_DATE,RESPONSE_TIME,IS_ERROR) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

private synchronized void saveToDBAndClear(ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Logs> logs) {
    List<Logs> list = new ArrayList<>(logs.values());
    logService.insertLog(list);
    initLogMap();
}


    public void insertLog(List<Logs> logsList) {

        int[] insertedLog = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(1, logsList.get(i).getMethod());
                ps.setString(2, logsList.get(i).getUser());
                ps.setTimestamp(3, logsList.get(i).getStartDate());
                ps.setLong(4, logsList.get(i).getResponseTime());
                ps.setString(5, logsList.get(i).getIsError());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return logsList.size();
            }
        });
        logger.info("It was inserted {} logs into Logs", insertedLog.length);
    }
```

And I must do

```
List<Logs> list = new ArrayList<>(logs.values());
```

because I do not know how to use `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()`

for each `ConcurrentHashMap` and collect batch in 100 or 1000 volume for pushing into DB.

Can someone help me with that?

**P.S.**

I`ve tried with that

```
public class LogProcessor {
private int batchSize = 10;
private final double initialCapacity = 1.26;
private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Logs> logMap;
private AtomicLong logMapSize;

    private void initLogMap() {
this.logMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>((int) (batchSize * initialCapacity));
this.logMapSize = new AtomicLong();
    }

public void process(LogKeeper keeper){
 LogHandler log = keeper.getLog();
 Long i = logMapSize.incrementAndGet();
 logMap.put(i, log.toJdbc());
 System.out.println("Lines inside the map = "+logMap.size());
 if (i % batchSize == 0) {
  System.out.println("Reached batchSize and = " + batchSize);
                    saveToDBAndClear(logMap);
                }

private synchronized void saveToDBAndClear(ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Logs> logs) {
List<Logs> list = new ArrayList<>(logs.values());
System.out.println("Created list with size = "+ list.size());
logService.insertLog(list);
initLogMap();
System.out.println("Now size of map = "+ logs.size()+" and AtomicLong = "+logMapSize.intValue() );
}

    @TransactionalRollback
    public void insertLog(List<Logs> logsList) {
        System.out.println("Inside insertLog method");
        int[][] insertedLog=jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT, logsList, 15, (ps, arg) -> {
            ps.setString(1, arg.getMethod());
            ps.setString(2, arg.getClient());
            ps.setTimestamp(3, arg.getStartDate());
            ps.setLong(4, arg.getResponseTime());
            ps.setString(5, arg.getIsError());
        });
        System.out.println("It was inserted " + insertedLog[0].length + " logs into DB");
    }
}
```

[image: And there is some log information]

And now, as you can see. My batchSize as a private field is 10. In batchUpdate, I put 15. I suppose, that if I send into insertLog method list, for example with size equals 1 or 100 it will collect to batches with size equal 15 and would be sending into DB, but in insert only that volume which list consists.

Because of that, I must collect exactly that batchSize which I need in my Map and then send it into insertLog method. If I could, I'd send only Logs log into insertLog method and put something like

```
 public void insertLog(Logs logs){
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT, logs, 1000, (ps, arg) ->(...));}
```

After that P.S. could someone help with that bathSize insert? Is it possible to make batchInsert or batchUpdate without that plain verification like 10%batchSize=0 ?

Comment: If you're asking how to execute the updates in batches of 1000, did you consider using the [`batchUpdate(java.lang.String sql, java.util.Collection<T> batchArgs, int batchSize, ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<T> pss)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-int-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter-) overload?

Comment: @Andreas 
If I found [correct](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_multiple_batches.htm) so It is not I'm looking for.
I try
`public void insertLog(List<Logs> logsList) { jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT, list, 15, (ps,arg)->{
                ps.setString(1, arg.getMethod());
                ps.setString(2, arg.getClient());
            }
        });`
And it inserted 10 and again 10, and again 10 elements, which was in list, not collect 15 rows as I suppoused.
And anyway, I can't insert intto batchUpdate my Object, I must insert there any Collection

Comment: How do you know it insert 10 at a time, not 15? --- What do you mean by *"not collect 15 rows as I suppoused"* given that it's not supposed to "collect" anything? --- What do you mean by *"I can't insert intto batchUpdate my Object, I must insert there any Collection"*? Your code uses a collection (`logsList`). The new code can use `logs.values()` directly without converting to `List` first, but is otherwise the same on that point.

Comment: About converting to the List, u`re correct. ---_How do you know it insert 10 at a time, not 15?_ I have logger.info(...) about it, and I see, that it was inserted 10 rows, but not 15.
Now, I collect batch in Map, till the count of logs less than 100 like `logs%100=0` But I want make batchUpdate(....logs.value, 100) and inside that method on the Oracle level, or jdbc, or jpa, it should collect my values ( rows ) in the memory and when it reaches 100, it will send into DB

Comment: Still have no idea what you're talking about "collecting" anything. You have already *collected* everything you need in the `logsList`. You then call the 4 parameter version of `batchUpdate`, with that list, asking it to batch the updates 15 at a time. Edit the question and show the code where you've tried that, and include (subset of) the logs created that shows it's only batching 10 at a time, because I cannot see how that can happen, given that you're not notified when it executes a batch, but since I cannot see what you've done, it's difficult to say.

Comment: Try enabling `trace` logging for `org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor`, since that should then log messages like `Sending SQL batch update #1 with 15 items`, proving that it's batching 15 at a time.

Comment: @Andreas , Any ideas after my P.S ?

Comment: The original question sounded like you had a large list of records to be inserted, and were asking how to insert that in smaller batches. That is apparent not the case, so thanks for wasting our time. --- Now it seems as though the `process` method is called once for each record to be inserted, and you want to collect them in batches, which is exactly what your code is doing, although why you need a intermediate `Map` is unknown. Since the code collects a batch and then calls `insertLog`, the original code should be working fine, so it's unclear what was originally wrong.

Comment: No. You are not correct here. In my question,before P.S. is my real code,which I use now. And I exactly need to collect my logs into Map and then into List. Why Map,you ask me, because I need concurrent collection to use in multithreading. After P.S, I show you new code,which also in batchUpdate doesn't work as I need. I repeat, I want to send any volume of my Logs ,as single object, Map with 1,100,1000 elements,or List,it doesn't matter, bit it Should sends to DB as batch with 1000 rows,for example. Now,I can make that only with `i%batchSize==0`

Comment: If you want database *batch* size of 1000, regardless of size of collected logs, use new code with 1000 instead of 15. If you want that batch size to actually have meaning, make sure you *collect* more than that in the `process` method before calling `saveToDBAndClear`. I really don't see what more you're asking about. --- Though I'm wondering why you'd want to collect more than 1000 in memory, using more memory than needed.

Comment: Ok, anyway thank you. I just don't know how to explain what I want and what I get after code and log`s screen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PLSQLSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples/PLSQLSample.java) for reference

Comment: Yes, it looks like a good, but It`s not that I`m looking for, because I have jdbc connection which is realized by Spring and I didn`t find any good variant for my situation.